# 'Get-WBJob' and 'Get-WBSummary' unrecognised commands

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am using a script that is set to run every morning read if teh last backup failed or completed and then puts it into a html page. This works fine on all of our 2012/2012R2 servers using the

```
Get-WBJob
```

and

```
Get-WBSummary
```

commands but this doesn't work on server 2008 Is there any alternative for those commands on this server version or is syntax slightly different? Please see below for relevant parts of the script. The 2008 server is also running version 2.0 of powershell

```
$WBJob = Get-WBJob
$WBSummary = Get-WBSummary
$WBErrorMsg = $WBJob.ErrorDescription + "'n" + $WBSummary.DetailedMessage
$WBResult = $WBSummary.LastBackupResultHR
```

Comment: Did you load/install the module that contains these cmdlets?

Comment: sorry yes i did i simply forgot to include it. At the beginning of the script i have this to load the PSSnapin 'Add-PSSnapin Windows.ServerBackup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'

Answer (score 0):

On Server 2008 you need to install it first, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732081.aspx

> In the Add Features Wizard, on the Select Features page, expand Windows Server Backup Features, and then select the check boxes for Windows Server Backup and Command-line Tools.